# A is a formula in Disjunctive Normal Form. A is very large with hundreds of variables and thousands of disjuncts. Which assertions are true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1. A cannot possibly be a tautology
2. It is easy to check whether A is satisfiable
3. Not every formula has DNF, so this is not particularly interesting

My reasoning:

1. A can be a tautology if the individual clauses are a tautology. But we don't know the value of the individual clauses so we cannot assume that A cannot be a tautology.
2. It would be very hard to construct a truth table for A if it has so many variables, right?
3. Every formula has an equivalent DNF/ CNF so how is this the case?

Please help me.

Comment: Do you really have to construct the whole truth table?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your answer is correct, but the reasoning isn't.

Let's take an example with 2 variables x and y, and look at a few DNF formulas that all describe the function that always returns "true", so they are all a tautology (I use the bar above a term to describe it's negation):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
 A  & = & x \lor \bar{x} \\
 A  & = & y \lor \bar{y} \\
 A  & = & xy \lor \bar{x}y \lor \bar{y} \\
 A  & = & xy \lor \bar{x}y \lor x\bar{y} \lor \bar{x}\bar{y}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Note that none of the indivudual clauses are tautologies  ($x$ from the first isn't one, nor $\bar{x}\bar{y}$ from the last). Also note that the first formula would be a valid DNF even for hundreds of variables, while the last formula, if extended to have all possible terms containing all variables, will contain $2^n$ clauses, if the number of variables is $n$.

My above examples show that any number of clauses can be a tautology. To check if they are, you need to basically construct the entire truth table until you are done or found a way to set the variables that make the formula produce the value "false".

To make that clear, since the disjunctive normal form is a big logical "or" clause, you can't just look at one clause in isolation, you have to ceck all together, as even if 99 clause return "false", clause 100 might return true.

2. Again your reasoning is incorrect, though I can see both answers being considered correct, depending on how "easy" it has to be.

Being satisfiable is much easier to check, because

a) you need to provide only one varaible setting that produces "true", instead of checking that all do, and

b) since the DNF is a big logical or clause, you need to find only one varaible setting that produces true for a single clause!

On a algorithmic level, this is much easier than for 1), as you can check clauses in isolation one after the other. You need linear time to go through all clauses one by one and check in each if variables appear both negated and non-negated. If one clause reads

$$x_1\overline{x_{17}}x_{34}\ldots x_{17}\ldots$$

then it is not satisfiable, as the part $\overline{x_{17}}x_{17}$ will never be true. OTOH, if that doesn't happen, then the clause is satisfiable, just choose each varaible such that it's occurrance in the clause (negated or not) becomes true.

Again, this is algorithmically not hard and goes fast (need to ceck each variable in each clause once in the worst case, and keep usage of a variable in each clause), so it could be argued that it's easy.

OTOH, doing that by hand for thousands of clauses and hundreds of variables is not easy, you are bound to make a mistake at some time if it turns out you don't already find a setting for the first or second clause.

3)
Well, since you seem to know that every formula can be transformed into an equivalent one in DNF, the statement's premise is wrong. But logic says that an implication with a wrong premise is always true, so the statement is true.

**ADDENDUM:**
As pointed out by Andreas Blass in the comments, a better interpretation of proposition 3 would be

$$ A \land (A \Rightarrow B)$$

with $A$ being "Not every formula has a DNF" and $B$ being "this is not interesting". This would make 3) a conjunction of a fals statement $A$ and a true implication, so 3) would be **wrong**.

Comment: Assertion 3 doesn't seem to be just an implication. I'd read it as the conjunction of "Not every formula has a DNF" and "If not every formula has a DNF then  this isn't very interesting" (and maybe also "This isn't very interesting"). So I'd say it's false because the first conjunct is false.

Comment: You might be right on this, it's a very plausible interpretation!